# kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to parse the broker info from zookeeper

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, ignite

I have deployed kafka in kubernetes using https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka. But while consuming using kafka consumer, I get following error :

```
SEVERE: Failed to resolve default logging config file: config/java.util.logging.properties
[10:23:00]    __________  ________________ 
[10:23:00]   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/ 
[10:23:00]  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/   
[10:23:00] /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/  
[10:23:00] 
[10:23:00] ver. 1.9.0#20170302-sha1:a8169d0a
[10:23:00] 2017 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
[10:23:00] 
[10:23:00] Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org
[10:23:00] 
[10:23:00] Quiet mode.
[10:23:00]   ^-- To see **FULL** console log here add -DIGNITE_QUIET=false or "-v" to ignite.{sh|bat}
[10:23:00] 
[10:23:00] OS: Linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 amd64
[10:23:00] VM information: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-1~deb9u1-b13 Oracle Corporation OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.181-b13
[10:23:02] Configured plugins:
[10:23:02]   ^-- None
[10:23:02] 
[10:23:02] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[10:23:02] Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
[10:23:03] REST protocols do not start on client node. To start the protocols on client node set '-DIGNITE_REST_START_ON_CLIENT=true' system property.
[10:23:24] Topology snapshot [ver=8, servers=1, clients=1, CPUs=112, heap=53.0GB]
[10:23:34] Performance suggestions for grid  (fix if possible)
[10:23:34] To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
[10:23:34]   ^-- Enable G1 Garbage Collector (add '-XX:+UseG1GC' to JVM options)
[10:23:34]   ^-- Specify JVM heap max size (add '-Xmx<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[10:23:34]   ^-- Set max direct memory size if getting 'OOME: Direct buffer memory' (add '-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>[g|G|m|M|k|K]' to JVM options)
[10:23:34]   ^-- Disable processing of calls to System.gc() (add '-XX:+DisableExplicitGC' to JVM options)
[10:23:34] Refer to this page for more performance suggestions: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning
[10:23:34] 
[10:23:34] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
[10:23:34] 
[10:23:34] Ignite node started OK (id=c10d143b)
[10:23:34] Topology snapshot [ver=7, servers=1, clients=2, CPUs=168, heap=80.0GB]
start creating caches
inside caches
{xgboostMainCache=IgniteCacheProxy [delegate=GridDhtAtomicCache [deferredUpdateMsgSnd=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$3@66c83fc8, near=null, super=GridDhtCacheAdapter [multiTxHolder=java.lang.ThreadLocal@ae7950d, super=GridDistributedCacheAdapter [super=GridCacheAdapter [locMxBean=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheLocalMetricsMXBeanImpl@6fd1660, clusterMxBean=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheClusterMetricsMXBeanImpl@4a6c18ad, aff=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.affinity.GridCacheAffinityImpl@5e8604bf, igfsDataCache=false, mongoDataCache=false, mongoMetaCache=false, igfsDataCacheSize=null, igfsDataSpaceMax=0, asyncOpsSem=java.util.concurrent.Semaphore@20095ab4[Permits = 500], name=xgboostMainCache, size=0]]]], opCtx=null], xgboostTrainedDataColumnSetCache=IgniteCacheProxy [delegate=GridDhtAtomicCache [deferredUpdateMsgSnd=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$3@53e3a87a, near=null, super=GridDhtCacheAdapter [multiTxHolder=java.lang.ThreadLocal@4dafba3e, super=GridDistributedCacheAdapter [super=GridCacheAdapter [locMxBean=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheLocalMetricsMXBeanImpl@546621c4, clusterMxBean=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheClusterMetricsMXBeanImpl@621f89b8, aff=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.affinity.GridCacheAffinityImpl@f339eae, igfsDataCache=false, mongoDataCache=false, mongoMetaCache=false, igfsDataCacheSize=null, igfsDataSpaceMax=0, asyncOpsSem=java.util.concurrent.Semaphore@2822c6ff[Permits = 500], name=xgboostTrainedDataColumnSetCache, size=0]]]], opCtx=null]}
end creating caches
start creating data streamers
end creating  data streamers
Launching Prediction Module
41098 [main] INFO  kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Verifying properties
41527 [main] INFO  kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property auto.offset.reset is overridden to smallest
41528 [main] WARN  kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property bootstrap.servers is not valid
41528 [main] INFO  kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property group.id is overridden to IgniteGroup_1
41528 [main] INFO  kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to zookeeper.kafka:2181
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:rsrc:slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:rsrc:slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
42290 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], Connecting to zookeeper instance at zookeeper.kafka:2181
42315 [ZkClient-EventThread-145-zookeeper.kafka:2181] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread  - Starting ZkClient event thread.
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:host.name=marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_181
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.class.path=marvelClient.jar
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:os.name=Linux
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:os.version=3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64
42332 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:user.name=root
42333 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:user.home=/root
42333 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:user.dir=/opt/marvel-files
42334 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper.kafka:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@7efb53af
42361 [main] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient  - Waiting for keeper state SyncConnected
47376 [main-SendThread(zookeeper.kafka.svc.cluster.local:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to server zookeeper.kafka.svc.cluster.local/10.109.79.222:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
47379 [main-SendThread(zookeeper.kafka.svc.cluster.local:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to zookeeper.kafka.svc.cluster.local/10.109.79.222:2181, initiating session
47390 [main-SendThread(zookeeper.kafka.svc.cluster.local:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Session establishment complete on server zookeeper.kafka.svc.cluster.local/10.109.79.222:2181, sessionid = 0x1009662f1130001, negotiated timeout = 6000
47394 [main-EventThread] INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient  - zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
47421 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], starting auto committer every 60000 ms
47476 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], begin registering consumer IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338 in ZK
47522 [main] INFO  kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral  - Creating /consumers/IgniteGroup_1/ids/IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338 (is it secure? false)
47539 [main] INFO  kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral  - Result of znode creation is: OK
47539 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], end registering consumer IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338 in ZK
47549 [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338_watcher_executor] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], starting watcher executor thread for consumer IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338
47591 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], begin rebalancing consumer IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338 try #0
47826 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], exception during rebalance 
kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to parse the broker info from zookeeper: {"listener_security_protocol_map":{"OUTSIDE":"PLAINTEXT","PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["OUTSIDE://kafka-0.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9094","PLAINTEXT://kafka-0.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092"],"jmx_port":5555,"host":"kafka-0.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local","timestamp":"1537867771273","port":9094,"version":4}
    at kafka.cluster.Broker$.createBroker(Broker.scala:101)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getCluster$1.apply(ZkUtils.scala:587)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getCluster$1.apply(ZkUtils.scala:585)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.getCluster(ZkUtils.scala:585)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$syncedRebalance$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcVI$sp(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:645)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$syncedRebalance$1.apply$mcV$sp(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:637)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$syncedRebalance$1.apply(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:637)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$syncedRebalance$1.apply(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:637)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:636)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$$reinitializeConsumer(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:977)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.consume(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:264)
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:85)
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:97)
    at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.KafkaStreamer.start(KafkaStreamer.java:135)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.models.xgboost.XgboostPrediction.startIgniteKafkaStreamer(XgboostPrediction.java:239)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.models.xgboost.XgboostPrediction.start(XgboostPrediction.java:97)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.models.xgboost.XgboostModel.predict(XgboostModel.java:42)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.OUTSIDE
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.valueOf(SecurityProtocol.java:28)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.forName(SecurityProtocol.java:89)
    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.createEndPoint(EndPoint.scala:49)
    at kafka.cluster.Broker$$anonfun$1.apply(Broker.scala:90)
    at kafka.cluster.Broker$$anonfun$1.apply(Broker.scala:89)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at kafka.cluster.Broker$.createBroker(Broker.scala:89)
    ... 28 more
47829 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], end rebalancing consumer IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338 try #0
47829 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], Rebalancing attempt failed. Clearing the cache before the next rebalancing operation is triggered
47834 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager  - [ConsumerFetcherManager-1537871021697] Stopping leader finder thread
47834 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager  - [ConsumerFetcherManager-1537871021697] Stopping all fetchers
47836 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager  - [ConsumerFetcherManager-1537871021697] All connections stopped
47838 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], Cleared all relevant queues for this fetcher
47840 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], Cleared the data chunks in all the consumer message iterators
47841 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], Committing all offsets after clearing the fetcher queues
49844 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], begin rebalancing consumer IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338 try #1
49864 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], exception during rebalance 
kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to parse the broker info from zookeeper: {"listener_security_protocol_map":{"OUTSIDE":"PLAINTEXT","PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["OUTSIDE://kafka-0.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9094","PLAINTEXT://kafka-0.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092"],"jmx_port":5555,"host":"kafka-0.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local","timestamp":"1537867771273","port":9094,"version":4}
    at kafka.cluster.Broker$.createBroker(Broker.scala:101)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getCluster$1.apply(ZkUtils.scala:587)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getCluster$1.apply(ZkUtils.scala:585)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.getCluster(ZkUtils.scala:585)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$syncedRebalance$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcVI$sp(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:645)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$syncedRebalance$1.apply$mcV$sp(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:637)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$syncedRebalance$1.apply(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:637)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anonfun$syncedRebalance$1.apply(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:637)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:636)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$$reinitializeConsumer(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:977)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.consume(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:264)
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:85)
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:97)
    at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.KafkaStreamer.start(KafkaStreamer.java:135)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.models.xgboost.XgboostPrediction.startIgniteKafkaStreamer(XgboostPrediction.java:239)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.models.xgboost.XgboostPrediction.start(XgboostPrediction.java:97)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.models.xgboost.XgboostModel.predict(XgboostModel.java:42)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.OUTSIDE
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.valueOf(SecurityProtocol.java:28)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.forName(SecurityProtocol.java:89)
    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.createEndPoint(EndPoint.scala:49)
    at kafka.cluster.Broker$$anonfun$1.apply(Broker.scala:90)
    at kafka.cluster.Broker$$anonfun$1.apply(Broker.scala:89)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at kafka.cluster.Broker$.createBroker(Broker.scala:89)
    ... 28 more
53907 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], end rebalancing consumer IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338 try #3
53907 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], Rebalancing attempt failed. Clearing the cache before the next rebalancing operation is triggered
53907 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager  - [ConsumerFetcherManager-1537871021697] Stopping leader finder thread
53907 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager  - [ConsumerFetcherManager-1537871021697] Stopping all fetchers
53907 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager  - [ConsumerFetcherManager-1537871021697] All connections stopped
53908 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], Cleared all relevant queues for this fetcher
53908 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], Cleared the data chunks in all the consumer message iterators
53908 [main] INFO  kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338], Committing all offsets after clearing the fetcher queues
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: kafka.common.ConsumerRebalanceFailedException: IgniteGroup_1_marvel-client-786884fdc8-z679b-1537871016569-2b7b1338 can't rebalance after 4 retries
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener.syncedRebalance(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:670)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.kafka$consumer$ZookeeperConsumerConnector$$reinitializeConsumer(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:977)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.consume(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:264)
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:85)
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:97)
    at org.apache.ignite.stream.kafka.KafkaStreamer.start(KafkaStreamer.java:135)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.models.xgboost.XgboostPrediction.startIgniteKafkaStreamer(XgboostPrediction.java:239)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.models.xgboost.XgboostPrediction.start(XgboostPrediction.java:97)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.models.xgboost.XgboostModel.predict(XgboostModel.java:42)
    at com.catpain.perc.marvel.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:211)
    ... 5 more
```

I have started Kafka Consumer from Apache Ignite 1.9.0 version(Using Ignite Kafka Streamer). Following are the consumer properties used :

```
ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_VALUE=zookeeper.kafka:2181
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_VALUE=bootstrap.kafka:9092
AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_VALUE=smallest
CONSUMER_GROUP_ID_VALUE=IgniteGroup_1
TOPIC_NAME=PAKDD_27_low_rate
```

Where `zookeeper` and `bootstrap` are the services and `kafka` is namespace. What might be the issue here and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Looks like an issue with the versions. Try updating Kafka to a newer version.
Also this this thread https://github.com/linkedin/kafka-monitor/issues/88.

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov Thanks. Updating Kafka Version to 0.10.2.1 on consumer side solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Kafka Version to `0.10.2.1` on consumer side solved the issue!